# Minimum Number of Rooms for Fallout Shelter Endgame

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've picked up Fallout Shelter again recently and I'm building towards the endgame. All rooms are unlocked and I have an abundance of caps, and a good half of my dwellers are at lvl 50 full SPECIAL.

I'm still training a bunch of them, but a lot of my time is mostly focused on questing, gathering loot and building to the top level gear.

Now I never seem to be short of resources, but can anyone tell me their best setup for the endgame? I'd like to have as few of my people as possible in production rooms and split them out into more crafting rooms and pumping out med kits and radaways for my explorers. Does anyone know the most ideal setup for this kind of situation? I also have a lot of storage rooms and a whole bunch of training rooms, and I'm not sure how much power they'll be drawing. Any tips? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than power, storage and accommodation, I have one of each room type.

The NuKaCola, Garden, Purification Plant, Caffeteria, and 2x Water Treatment Plant give me more than enough food and water for 126 dwellers (I stopped collecting them as I can only do 3 quests at a time and my rooms don't need more).

- Water produced 86/min, water consumed 41/min
- Food produced 110/min, food consumed 41/min

I have 3 power plants and 1 nuclear reactor to power it all

- Power produced 184/min, power consumed 95/min

I could probably be more efficient by:

- having better dwellers in water production and sell a water treatment plant
- change 2 power plants to a nuke
- sell one power plant
- replace all food and water production with Cola (but I won't for variety)

Done efficiently, I think I need 5 resource buildings and 3 power buildings: 32 dwellers.

Add 2x hospitals and 2x science labs: +16 dwellers

3 x quests: +9 dewllers

That's a total of 55 dwellers.

In my vault the other 70 are in training rooms. You could more out exploring (is the limit 25 now?), and have the rest (60-100 depending on your population) in crafting rooms.

Can sell the training rooms, theme production and barber for power saving if you want to be efficient and have room for more weapon production.

Build new nuke reactors as necessary if the crafting rooms use more power than the training rooms you are replacing.

Comment: I shall try with 3 power rooms and 4 nuka cola and see how that goes

Comment: That seems like a lot of production rooms.

I've only just gone through the 100 dweller barrier and got the ability to build Cola bottlers, maybe I'll need more when I've got more people, But all I have is two triple-size nuclear reactors, one cola plant and a cafeteria (plus a water plant with nobody in it). The cafeteria will be emptied soon when I have something for its current staff to do. All rooms are fully upgraded and fully occupied by six dwellers with 10 in the appropriate stat and bonus gear as well. That gives me all the resources I need.